# Split string function

Tags: c

I'm coding a split function, this is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split ( const char *s1, const char *s2) {

    char **lista;
    char *aux = s1;
    char *token_Ptr;
    int i = 0;
    
    lista = (char **) malloc (sizeof (char *));
    token_Ptr = strtok(aux, s2);
    lista[i] = token_Ptr;
    while(token_Ptr != NULL)
    {
        lista = (char **)realloc(lista, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
        token_Ptr = strtok(NULL, s2);
        i++;
        lista[i] = token_Ptr;
    }
    return lista;
}

int main ( int argc , char *argv[]) {

    char **MILISTA;
    int i;

    if (argc==2) {
        printf ("Cadena: '%s'\n",argv[1]);
        MILISTA= split(argv[1]," ");
        i=0;
        puts("----------------TOKENS------------");
        while (MILISTA[i]!=NULL) {
            printf("%s, " , MILISTA[i++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        puts("----------------FIN---------------");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But i've got some errors:

```
facu@linux:~/projects/spliting/bin/Debug$ ./spliting "HOLA MUNDO COMO s"
Cadena: 'HOLA MUNDO COMO s'
*** glibc detected *** ./spliting: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x09e12008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x17c501]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x71c6d)[0x181c6d]
/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0xe3)[0x181f53]
./spliting[0x8048573]
./spliting[0x80485fa]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x126ce7]
./spliting[0x8048471]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00267000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 8526       /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
00267000-00269000 r--p 00157000 08:06 8526       /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
00269000-0026a000 rw-p 00159000 08:06 8526       /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
0026a000-0026d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00573000-0058d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 251        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0058d000-0058e000 r--p 00019000 08:06 251        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0058e000-0058f000 rw-p 0001a000 08:06 251        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0065a000-0065b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
007f1000-00815000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 8577       /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
00815000-00816000 r--p 00023000 08:06 8577       /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
00816000-00817000 rw-p 00024000 08:06 8577       /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
00c2d000-00d0c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 660319     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00d0c000-00d10000 r--p 000de000 08:06 660319     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00d10000-00d11000 rw-p 000e2000 08:06 660319     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00d11000-00d18000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00e86000-00ea2000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 8518       /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
00ea2000-00ea3000 r--p 0001b000 08:06 8518       /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
00ea3000-00ea4000 rw-p 0001c000 08:06 8518       /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 262453     /home/facu/projects/spliting/bin/Debug/spliting
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:08 262453     /home/facu/projects/spliting/bin/Debug/spliting
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:08 262453     /home/facu/projects/spliting/bin/Debug/spliting
09e12000-09e33000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7700000-b7721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7721000-b7800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7870000-b7873000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7888000-b788b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bf834000-bf855000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Abortado
```

If i only parse: "HOLA MUNDO COMO" the program runs correctly...

How should i solve it?

Comment: do you think that my function is good? some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change the content of `argv` (note that `strtok` will modify the string passed).

The rest of the function is almost correct, however you are calling `realloc` to make space for `(i+1)` elements while `i` is still 0. So basically you are allocating space for one pointer less than needed. Just move `i++;` to the beginning of the loop and everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the first advice! I will take it!

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use valgrind. This is one of the most useful tool to diagnose these kind of errors.

`$valgrind ./a.out "HOLA MUNDO COMO s"
==4949== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4949== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4949== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4949== Command: ./a.out HOLA\ MUNDO\ COMO\ s
==4949== 
Cadena: 'HOLA MUNDO COMO s'
==4949== Invalid write of size 8
==4949==    at 0x40070B: split (a.c:20)
==4949==    by 0x40076B: main (a.c:32)
==4949==  Address 0x518a098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==4949==    at 0x4C245E2: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==4949==    by 0x4006DC: split (a.c:17)
==4949==    by 0x40076B: main (a.c:32)
==4949== 
----------------TOKENS------------
==4949== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4949==    at 0x4007BF: main (a.c:35)`

what this thing says, is that, on line 20, you tried to write à pointer after the end of your table.

which is true : you allocate a table of size i+1, then you increment i and you access table[i], which is not allocated. For example, The first time you enter the loop, you reallocate a table of 1 chars* (so you're not growing it), and you access a second element of your table. the second time you enter the loop, you grow your array to a size of 2 and you access the third element/

the second error, on line 35, mean that your MILISTA table have some parts that are not initialized because of the wrong behaviour of the first loop.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to learn to use valgrind! Very usefull your answer!

Answer (score 2):

strtok modifies the source string. You can't modify the argument string (it's read only). Copy the original string in another string. And when you realloc, instead of +1 use +2 (when i = 0, you already have an element).

This:

> ```
> char **split ( const char *s1, const char *s2) {
>
>     char **lista;
>     char *aux = (char*)malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
>     strcpy(aux, s1);
>     char *token_Ptr;
>     int i = 0;
>
>     lista = (char **) malloc (sizeof (char *));
>     token_Ptr = strtok(aux, s2);
>     lista[i] = token_Ptr;
>     i++;
>     while(token_Ptr != NULL)
>     {
>         lista = (char **)realloc(lista, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
>         token_Ptr = strtok(NULL, s2);
>         lista[i] = token_Ptr;
>         i++;
>     } 
>     return lista;
> }
> ```

You will have 2 pointers to free:
free(lista[0]) and free(lista).

This function is not good because it allocates memory. Very rarely a function should alloc memory. No, there isn't any solution to this problem :-) You simply must be careful to free the allocated memory.